# Creating UI elements programmatically in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, user-interface

I have been working on automating some aspects of creating UI elements and have created this method that seems to work:

```
    - (void) viewDidLoad
        {
            [super viewDidLoad];
            button = [self createButton:button xPos:30 yPos:100 width:100 height:30  caption:@"autoButton" textPos:NSTextAlignmentCenter textClr:[UIColor blackColor] backClr:[UIColor yellowColor]];
            [self.view addSubview: button];
        }

    - (UIButton *) createButton:(UIButton *)control xPos:(CGFloat)x yPos:(CGFloat)y width:(CGFloat)width height:(CGFloat)height caption:(NSString *)caption textPos:(NSTextAlignmentCenter)textPosition textClr:(UIColor *)textColor backClr:(UIColor *)backColor
        {
            control = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)];
            [control setTitle:caption forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            control.titleLabel.textAlignment = textPosition;
            control.backgroundColor = backColor;
            [control setTitleColor: textColor forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            return control;
        }
```

1. Is there anything wrong/bad with this implementation?
2. Instead of using methods, would it be possible to implement the same thing with just plain old functions? It's a little long-winded to have to indicate the parameter names, ***xPos:30 yPos:100 width:100 height:100, etc.***

Would be nice to be able to just do something like:

```
button = createButton(30, 100, 100, 30, @"autoButton", NSTextAlignmentCenter, [UIColor blackColor], [UIColor yellowColor]);
```

Is this doable?

Comment: There's nothing necessarily wrong with the method you've already written but, depending on how/where you use the button, it might be a smarter idea to subclass UIButton and add a custom initializer. I wouldn't use a function like that since you aren't writing in C. I tend to prefer a subclass with a custom initializer to make the code more portable and modular.

Comment: @Dare: Doesn't that mean that all those custom subclassed UI classes must be imported separately?

Comment: Yes they need to be imported but Objective-C is an object oriented language. It's better practice, generally speaking, to utilize subclasses than to fill up a viewController with view initializers. It will work perfectly fine but it makes it more difficult if you want to use that method in any other class or even another project, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Fine except it makes no sense to pass in the `button` parameter. Just return a `UIButton` object.

   ```
   - (void) viewDidLoad
       {
           [super viewDidLoad];
           button = [self createButtonWithxPos:30 yPos:100 width:100 height:30  caption:@"autoButton" textPos:NSTextAlignmentCenter textClr:[UIColor blackColor] backClr:[UIColor yellowColor]];
           [self.view addSubview: button];
       }

   - (UIButton *) createButtonWithxPos:(CGFloat)x yPos:(CGFloat)y width:(CGFloat)width height:(CGFloat)height caption:(NSString *)caption textPos:(NSTextAlignmentCenter)textPosition textClr:(UIColor *)textColor backClr:(UIColor *)backColor
       {
           UIButton *control = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)];
           [control setTitle:caption forState:UIControlStateNormal];
           control.titleLabel.textAlignment = textPosition;
           control.backgroundColor = backColor;
           [control setTitleColor: textColor forState:UIControlStateNormal];
           return control;
       }
   ```
2. Fine, use a function or a method. Up to you. As long as you don't need `self` involved, a function works.

   ```
   UIButton *createButton(CGFloat x, CGFloat y, CGFloat width, CGFloat height, NSString *caption, NSTextAlignmentCenter textPosition, UIColor *textColor, UIColor *backColor) {
       UIButton *control = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)];
       [control setTitle:caption forState:UIControlStateNormal];
       control.titleLabel.textAlignment = textPosition;
       control.backgroundColor = backColor;
       [control setTitleColor: textColor forState:UIControlStateNormal];
       return control;
   }

   - (void) viewDidLoad
       {
           [super viewDidLoad];
           button = createButton(30, 100, 100, 30, @"autoButton", NSTextAlignmentCenter, [UIColor blackColor], [UIColor yellowColor]);
           [self.view addSubview: button];
       }
   ```

Comment: Thank you very much! Above and beyond what I expected - questions answered with working solutions to boot. Truly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the category **built-in feature in Objective-c**:
1.[Apple documentary for customising classes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html)

2.[Categories tutorial](http://rypress.com/tutorials/objective-c/categories)

Comment: This answer would be far more useful if you explained how those concepts actually could be used to answer the question.

Comment: it is much more correct way to add methods to view objects in IOS