# UIButton with action-selector method in different class

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, action, addtarget

Related to this previous question ([Creating UI elements programmatically in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30266174/creating-ui-elements-programmatically-in-objective-c)), this method resides in one class of the project, and other classes are able to call it to programmatically create buttons:

```
    UIButton *createButton(CGFloat x, CGFloat y, CGFloat width, CGFloat height, NSString *caption, NSTextAlignmentCenter textPosition, UIColor *textColor, UIColor *backColor) {
            UIButton *control = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)];
            [control setTitle:caption forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            control.titleLabel.textAlignment = textPosition;
            control.backgroundColor = backColor;
            [control setTitleColor: textColor forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            return control;
    }
```

I am now trying to add the target and action methods, to be handled by a common function, like so:

```
[control addTarget:nil 
            action:@selector(commonHandler) 
  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
```

It works for buttons that reside in the same class as the *createButton()* function, but although the buttons are successfully created in the other classes as well, they don't trigger the *commonHandler()* method.

NOTE: the *createButton()* and *commonHandler()* methods have been declared in its header file, and imported by all classes.

Is there any way to achieve this?

---

**EDIT: The proposed solution still crashes**

I modified the code as per the suggestions, and converted both the *createButton* and *buttonAction* to Objective-C methods, to enable reference to *self*.

*class1 header*

```
    // class1.h

    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import "class2.h"

    @interface class1 : UIViewController {
        UIButton *button1;
    }

    - (void) buttonAction:(UIButton *)control;

    - (UIButton *) createButtonWithxPos:(CGFloat)x
                                   yPos:(CGFloat)y
                                  width:(CGFloat)width
                                 height:(CGFloat)height
                                caption:(NSString *)caption
                                textPos:(NSTextAlignment)textPosition
                                textClr:(UIColor *)textColor
                                backClr:(UIColor *)backColor;

    @end
```

*class1 implementation*

```
    // class1.m

    #import "class1.h"
    #import "class2.h"

    @implementation class1
    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        button1 = [self createButtonWithxPos:10
                                        yPos:10 
                                       width:200 
                                      height:30 
                                     caption:@"Cls1 Button"
                                     textPos:NSTextAlignmentCenter 
                                     textClr:[UIColor whiteColor] 
                                     backClr:[UIColor blackColor]];

        [self.view addSubview: button1];    
    }

    - (UIButton *) createButtonWithxPos:(CGFloat)x
                                   yPos:(CGFloat)y
                                  width:(CGFloat)width
                                 height:(CGFloat)height
                                caption:(NSString *)caption
                                textPos:(NSTextAlignment)textPosition
                                textClr:(UIColor *)textColor
                                backClr:(UIColor *)backColor 
    {
        UIButton *control = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)];
        [control setTitle:caption forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        control.titleLabel.textAlignment = textPosition;
        control.backgroundColor = backColor;
        [control setTitleColor: textColor forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [control addTarget:self action: @selector(buttonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
        return control;
    }

    - (void) buttonAction:(UIButton *)control {
        NSLog(@"button clicked...");
    }

    @end
```

*class2 header*

```
    // class2.h

    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

    @interface class2 : UIViewController {
        UIButton *button2;
    }
    @end
```

*class2 implementation*

```
    // class2.m

    #import "class1.h"
    #import "class2.h"

    @implementation class2

    - (void) viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        class1 *cls1 = [[class1 alloc] init];
        button2 = [cls1 createButtonWithxPos:10
                                        yPos:10 
                                       width:200 
                                      height:30 
                                     caption:@"Cls2 Button"
                                     textPos:NSTextAlignmentCenter 
                                     textClr:[UIColor whiteColor] 
                                     backClr:[UIColor blackColor]];

        [self.view addSubview: button2];
    }

    @end
```

Both *button1* and *button2* are created properly, but *button1* triggers the *buttonAction* method while *button2* does not - it crashes on touch.

Is it implemented wrongly?

*(please excuse any omissions as I have only extracted the relevant portions from the actual project to illustrate here)*

Comment: You must set the target to `self` for the class in which the button instance resides. Also, the corresponding selector must be in located in that class.

Comment: The target needs to be set to the class instance that supports the `commonHandler` method. Passing `nil` for the target will never work.

Comment: @Nikita: How could I do that? Pass the *self* object as a parameter, perhaps?

Comment: @Nikita Sorry but that statement is incorrect. The target does not need to be where the button exists. The requirement is that the given target must implement the provided selector, regardless of where the button resides.

Comment: @rmaddy: You're right. But I can't seem to pass the *self* object into the function. NIL works for the buttons that reside in the same class as *commonHandler()* though.

Comment: @rmaddy Yep, you are correct)

Comment: @iSofia Why can't you pass the desired target to your `createButton` method as a parameter?

Comment: @rmaddy: The buttons created in the same class as *commonHandler()* can simply pass *self* as the object. But how do I pass *self* when calling from another class? Wouldn't it be the wrong class?

Comment: If `commonHandler` and `createButton` are in the same class, then simply pass `self` as the target. It will work. It won't matter what class calls `createButton`.

Comment: @rmaddy: Sorry. So, you mean that even a button to be created in another class can simply call the *createButton()* function with an added parameter of *NSObject self*? But won't that *self* be its own class, and not the *self* of the target class *(where the createButton & commonHandler resides)*?

Comment: I don't know what you mean. When you call `[someButton addTarget:self action@selector(commonHandler) forControlEvents:...];` the `self` is the `self` of whatever class is calling that line of code. It's not the button, it's not whatever class is calling `createButton`. It's the class that contains the `createButton` method (and apparently also the `commonHandler` method).

Comment: @rmaddy: I'm not able to hard-code the *self* object because *createButton()* is a function and not an Objective-C method. It'll throw an *undeclared identifier 'self'* error.

Comment: After adding a new parameter *NSObject self* to the *createButton()* function, it works, but only for buttons created in the same class. Those created in different classes crash when clicked.

Comment: The `createButton` method you posted in your question is an Objective-C method, not a function. If you have another `createButton` function, you will need to make it a method to do what you want.

Comment: @rmaddy: Wow! I posted the wrong snippet - yours in fact. So, no way of accessing the *self* object from within a function? Methods are just so verbose, with their descriptors.

Comment: You're making this way too complicated. Make `createButton` a method instead of a function and use the method the way you're trying to, but pass `self` instead of `nil`. It'll work fine. You are going to get a lot more verbose trying to use a function instead of a method here.

Comment: @iSofia So createButton and commonHandler are both functions? If that's the case, I should have said make them both methods

Comment: @rmaddy: For some reason it still doesn't respond after making the changes. I've posted the modified code - is that how you proposed it?